# DoxyGen ignores functions

Tags: c++, documentation, doxygen

I have a file like:

```
/** @file some description */

void SomeFunc();///< brief function description
```

The *@file* keyword is needed to document global functions, [as per Doxygen mailing list](http://doxygen.10944.n7.nabble.com/C-functions-missing-in-documentation-td3393.html). So here it is, but Doxygen keeps ignoring *SomeFunc()*, i.e. it doesn't appear anywhere in documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `@file` keyword is used to [specify the file name](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdfile), not the description. Try something like this:

```
//!
//! @file filename.h
//! @brief some description
//!
```

Comment: Thank you very much, yes, this made a trick. To sum up: it was needed to place name of the file after the `@file` keyword.